# Error: SetSite failed for package [ApacheCordovaToolsPackage]

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I just installed both Visual studio 2015 and visual studio cordova tools.
It wrked fine and i was able to create a project with it.

I then installed ionic cli, and suddenly i am getting the error

```
SetSite failed for package [ApacheCordovaToolsPackage]
```

I have tried repairing Visual studio and cordova tools to no avail.
Any help?

Comment: I've run into the same issue after installing the Win10 SDK.

Comment: Today I let VS install the updates to the TypeScript tools and the Cordova tools. Afterward I started hitting this, and the JS language service seems totally busted (and JS doesn't even show up in Options -> Text Editor under languages). So who totally hosed VS? Cordova or TypeScript?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The steps in [this MSDN forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0e5115ca-83a7-4294-8740-289b3f453fca/rtm-known-issue-package-load-failure-when-creating-a-windows-app-project-with-javascript-or-hang) worked for me. Reproducing for Googleability:

> Find the installer for Visual Studio 2015 in your installer cache.

```
cd /d "%ProgramData%\Package Cache"
dir vs*exe /s /b
```

> Find the path to vs_community.exe, vs_professional.exe, or vs_enterprise.exe, and copy that path.

(I found my `vs_enterprise.exe` at `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{a60a492e-b5eb-4218-a9e6-f38d18a7dbaf}\vs_enterprise.exe`)

CD into that path, e.g.,

```
cd {a60a492e-b5eb-4218-a9e6-f38d18a7dbaf}
```

Execute the installer with the options `/modify /installselectableitems Javascript`, e.g.,

```
vs_enterprise.exe /modify /installselectableitems Javascript
```

> In Visual Studio setup, select Modify then Update, without changing any feature selections.

Then:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
devenv /updateconfiguration
devenv /clearcache
```

Comment: As a side note, the VS Android emulator was still giving me an error on startup ("Couldn't change Display controller settings of the virtual machine"). After deleting the Android VM from Hyper-V Manager, it started working again.

Comment: I've been trying all morning to solve this, yours was the only fix that worked, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, thanks. I almost gave up on this. i didnt that a new product will have this kind of issue

Comment: I really don't recommend using VS tools for cordova/ionic, it is very buggy and won't give you the same flexibility as the cli tools.

Comment: Worked for me, Thanks!

Comment: If I do not change feature selection, the Update button remains disabled. I think I'll need to choose Repair instead.

Answer (score 10):

The solution in [Error adb.exe when running Visual Studio 2015 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631284/error-adb-exe-when-running-visual-studio-2015-rc) worked for me.
In short:
Delete this folder: C:\Users[username]\appdata\local\microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache

Then open a new project get the folder rebuild by VS.

Comment: I had a similar problem with Visual Studio 2019 and `IntelliCodeCppPackage`.  In the case of my 2019 install, the cache was in `16.0_1c277db3`, but you should just look for whatever folder.