# Error adb.exe when running Visual Studio 2015 RC

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015

When I try to deploy an application in VS 2015 with Tools for Apache Cordova (TACO), I get this error:

```
Unable to start program C:\users\pc\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

operation not supported. unknown error 0x80070057
```

I have confirmed that `adb.exe` exists in my computer

Comment: Update to the latest of VS 2015 and it will include all the latest bug fixes for Apache Cordova projects.  Hard to help when using RC versions.

Comment: LOL wrong answer, scott. Just upgraded from a working version to update 2 of the Cordova toolkit for VS2015 and I got this error in a previously working project. Totally hosed my install. Reinstalling android sdk tools didn't fix it either... I'm running vs2015 Professional, v14.0.23107.0 D14REL

Comment: Another symptom is with Ripple: Unable to get launched browser process for Ripple.
Unable to get Ripple session info. Exception: Unable to connect to the remote server. Please close all instances of Chrome and try again.

Comment: Trying a repair on MSVS Tools for Apache Cordova now. Will report on results.

Comment: After repair, different ripple error:
Unable to get launched browser process for Ripple.
Unable to get Ripple session info. Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.. Please close all instances of Chrome and try again.

Comment: Guess my only next option is to remove everything in update 2. Might have to do wtih the TypeScript tools 1.6.3.0 also. Let's find out!

Comment: @klatzib What is your proposal for me?

Comment: be patient for a solution is my proposal, I'm still trying. Been through 4 reboots trying different configs.

Comment: @klatzib  Here is output text after deploy http ://goo.gl/oBq8dA

Comment: @klatzib  How view minimum android version for aplication in visual stuido? I get .apk file but can not install on my android 4.2.2

Comment: nothing i tried worked including visual studio command line as admin calling devenv /setup nor devenv /installVSTemplates. Going to do full uninstall/reinstall now. This sucks.

Comment: Just got off a support session with Microsoft. They just became aware of this issue in the last few days and are hunting down the cause and solution. Will provide an answer if I get one then.

Answer (score 6):

Just got a response from Microsoft! Here is the answer that fixed it for me.

1) Delete this folder: C:\Users\[username]\appdata\local\microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache

2) Open Visual Studio and create a new blank cordova project. This will regenerate the deleted folder.

3) Debug the blank project in ripple, first run may complain about a problem with Chrome and the debugger may fail to connect. Close chrome after this, and try debugging one more time and it should connect as desired.

4) Enjoy a once-more functioning development environment!

Comment: nice answer! Worked for me

Comment: I tried this and the blank solution builded perfectly. But the buggy one still didn't. So i deleted my app on my phone and then it worked!

Answer (score 3):

Just for record, nothing above helped out with this issue.

After some effort, I decided to get a previous version of code, since I already had published the application on an Android device and didn't happend this error.

I noticed that I've made some changes in config.xml, and the change that was causing the problem was the "**Package Name**" on "**Common**" section. I've put a capitalized name, like "Mycompany.Packagename". When I changed to "com.mycompany.packagename", worked like a charm.

It's strange, since the error does not appear to be related to this, but I've tested and could simulate and replicated the error, so this is a warning: use lower case in the **Package Name** field.

Comment: This worked for me. I had a "-" in my name like "pre-fix". Changed it to "prefix" and now it works fine

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to fix this issue on my project by directly running the ADB command to install the APK file on my device to make it so I can see the actual reason the deploy to my phone was failing:

```
adb install android-debug.apk
```

Which gave me the error:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
```

which I was then able to google and find the solution to that problem.

Mine was failing because I had deleted my test version of the app from my phone but the reinstall of the test app was failing because the production app was loaded.

[INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE when I try to install compiled .apk on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891848/install-failed-update-incompatible-when-i-try-to-install-compiled-apk-on-device)

Your problem may be different than mine, but this methodology may allow you to track your problem down.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that simply performing the fix outlined at this link is sufficient: [Error: SetSite failed for package [ApacheCordovaToolsPackage]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31741405/error-setsite-failed-for-package-apachecordovatoolspackage/31834181#31834181)

But I didn't try it until I went through a full uninstall/reinstall of VS2015 pro.

Hidden folders at same level as .sln:
in path: .vs/{solutionname}/v14/

delete the file ".suo"

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of kltzib worked for me!! But more simple.

1) Delete this folder: C:\Users[username]\appdata\local\microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache

2) Open Visual Studio and debug the existing project.

Comment: Still facing this issue after trying both Bon's solution and Nacho's way. However, none of them working!!

Comment: I am able to build/ deploy a new blank cordova project, but the existing one - I am unable to deploy on device. It is working on Ripple though.

Comment: this worked for me. Had "...unknown error 0x80070057" no andoid sdk involved. A simple VS webforms app.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled the app from device, then tried to debug again; and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had same issue when trying to deploy/debug release version of app on both device and emulator.

Problem was solved when i signed my app with valid key for google play store.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem and after spend a lot time I solve it. The problem was in the file "config.xml" in the first line:

```
<?xml version="1.3" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

I change to the same but version="1.0":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

For some reason the visual studio threw me some time ago a compiler error due to this, but it stopped throwing it.

Comment: my config file has <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> already, but not standalone="yes"