# Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Apache Cordova Update 2 Template Not Found

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

Windows 10, VS 2015

I have just updated to Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova (Update 2) and: 
 1. My existing Cordova project is no longer loading
 2. In my add new project templates dialog, I can only find Cordova under TypeScript, and my JavaScript category has disapeared.
 3. If I try to add new project using the TypeScript Cordova template I get "the template specified cannot be found" error message.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the update several times, but it didn't help. Any suggestion?

Comment: This happened to me too, inspecting the error log lead me to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31834181/203371) SO answer which fixed this problem for me. It's getting tiresome that every update seems to trash the Cordova solutions/projects!

Comment: @BenSmith, thank you, it solved my problem.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BenSmith suggested an answer, while the answer is for a different question, it solved my problem:
[Error: SetSite failed for package [ApacheCordovaToolsPackage]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31741405/error-setsite-failed-for-package-apachecordovatoolspackage/31834181#31834181)